# Laptop Charges and drains quickly

Tags: battery

I have a 5-Month old Acer Aspire E5-571G.
My battery normally last for 8 to 9 hrs and charges within 2-3hrs. 
Now, anytime i plug the charger, the battery charges so fast that in 5mins,it would have acquired 30%. When it's fully charged and i start to use it on battery power, it just goes off when it gets to around 60%.
Any attempt to turn it on again, I would get critical Low Battery. 
Help please!  What can i do?

Comment: Buy a new battery.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will need a new battery.  However, if its under 5 months old, it might be under warranty.  Call Acer support to find out.

In addition to that,  follow the steps below to try and recalibrate your battery.

From Acer's [website](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11574/~/how-do-i-calibrate-my-battery%3F):

> How do I calibrate my battery?
>
> Calibrating your battery helps get a proper reading on your current battery charge. If your battery is dying before the reported time given in Windows, it could be that you need to calibrate your battery.
>
> Use the following steps to to re-calibrate the battery:
>
> Turn the notebook or netbook off. Plug in your AC adapter.
>
> Let the unit fully charge, until the battery LED turns off.
>
> Turn on the computer and press the F8 key repeatedly when the first logo screen appears.
>   In the Windows Advanced Startup menu, select Safe Mode and press the ENTER key.
>   Unplug the unit and let the computer run on battery until it shuts down.
>
> Note: The process to re-calibrate your battery can take several hours, depending on the battery lifetime and age, and the configuration of your system.

Comment: Just saw this 3-month old post again, your suggestion really worked for me, calibration was actually what it needed. Sorry i didn't thank you sooner, i was in a state of total disorderliness that i just grabbed the solution without thinking about its source

Comment: @Qudus No problem.  if it worked for you, upvote and select it as the answer.